# ESLint yoda ignores undefined comparison like foo === undefined

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have configured eslint having `'yoda': ["error", 'always']`

it works fine if i compare variable with `null`

```
if(foo === null) {} // eslint throws error
```

but if i compare `undefined` it ignore

```
if(foo === undefined) {} // eslint skip this
```

Comment: `undefined` *isn't* a literal like `null`, it's actually a global property.

Comment: A global property that cannot be assigned to (in modern browsers)

Comment: @jonrsharpe is there any alternative that check ```undefined```?

Comment: the classic way would be `typeof foo === "undefined"`

Comment: @Thomas but still i presume it should check ```foo === undefined``` too